# Enumerator new and yield

Tags: ruby

At ruby docs I found this piece of code:

```
fib = Enumerator.new do |y|
  a = b = 1
  loop do
    y << a
    a, b = b, a + b
  end
end
```

Thing is i cant understand what it does. In general it calculates fibonacci's numbers, but I have hard time understanding the details. What is `y (Enumerator::Yielder)`? The [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator/Yielder.html) says nothing about it. What does `<<` method do? (I know its yield alias). Why does infinite loop happen when `y << a` 
is removed?Thanks!

Comment: _The Well-Grounded Rubyist 2nd edition_ has a good section explaining enumerators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
fib = Enumerator.new do |y| 
  puts "Enter enumerator"
  a = b = 1 
  loop do
    puts "Inside loop"
    y << a
    puts "y: #{y.inspect}, a: #{a}, b: #{b}"
    a, b = b, a + b 
  end 
end
puts fib.take(5)
```

It prints:

```
# Enter enumerator
# Inside loop
# y: #<Enumerator::Yielder:0x000000059a27e8>, a: 1, b: 1
# Inside loop
# y: #<Enumerator::Yielder:0x000000059a27e8>, a: 1, b: 2
# Inside loop
# y: #<Enumerator::Yielder:0x000000059a27e8>, a: 2, b: 3
# Inside loop
# y: #<Enumerator::Yielder:0x000000059a27e8>, a: 3, b: 5
# Inside loop

# 1
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 5
```

Apparently, this output actually gives hints on all the question you’ve stated. Note, that we entered a yielder only *once*. Let’s dig into:

#### Why `loop` is infinite?

Because Fibonacci’s number sequence is infinite. This enumerator is intended to be used with [`Enumerable#take`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-take) (see an example above.)

#### What is `Enumerator::Yielder`?

It is an abstraction. It’s method `yield` actually calls back the block of callee, passing a parameter as block parameters.

#### What does `<<` method does?

Yields once. In other words, it calls back the caller code, passing it’s parameter to the caller’s block. In this particular example, it will call back `each` block, passing `a` from `Yielder` instance as block parameter (`e` as I named it there.)

#### Why does infinite loop happen when `y << a` is removed?

Because there are no `yield`s happened. In my example, the callee will stop after yielding five (5 as parameter of `take`) times.

Comment: i dont understand everything yet: if i go with puts fib.take(5) output is the same, there is no block, so what does y << do then? it appears to somehow return a value or pass it to invisible array, because fib.take(5) is an array. but how does this thing know it should stop after 5 loops is still beyond me

Comment: That is because `take` _evaluates_ an iterator to build an array.

Comment: so it evaluates the block, but the loop, does it evaluate until it gets 5 values to yield method? does it mean that you always need to pass the int when using methods on enumerator instance var? why isnt this method listed here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html ?

Comment: This method is listed on `Enmerable`, even more: I have _linked_ this method in the answer. `Enumerator` includes `Enumerable`. This particular `Enumerator` is infinite, hence it requires a method like `take` to specify a number of values. This is not a requirement for an `Enumerator`, one might implement exactly N iterations, as, e.g. the one returned from `Hash#each` does.